# what is the proper React Architecture?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In creating a React app, I'm currently creating an app where the parent component is handling and managing all the state changes.  I am passing down the necessary states and functions to each child as props.  Is this the 'preferred' way to do it or should the child components handle/manage their own states?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all boils down to one question,

**Is the component a re-usable, independent component?**

If yes, then it can have its own state and be plugged into any component without any hassle.

---

**It's a good idea to consider these pointers while deciding where to put the state.**

- There are components that **cannot** stand on its own but only be used in parent components. In that case, it's a good idea to store the state in parent and drill it down to the child.
- There are components that focus only on UI logic and not much, eg. an input box with validation. In these cases, it's a good idea to put the state of input validation in the component itself as the parent doesn't have to care about validation logic.
- If multiple child components depend on the data/value from parent, then it's a good idea to put the state in the parent.

The thumb rule is, **always store the state in the parent unless the child is totally independent and can be used on other parent components as well**.

Answer (score 2):

This approach will work for a while, but you'll soon find that your entire application logic is pushed up to the top component, and that you're passing it down through many nested layers of child components to get it where it needs to go.

One approach is to move various pieces of state down as far as you can (but no further). The [Thinking in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html) article discusses this. So if some state or state-changing functions are only needed by one sub-tree of your application, just put it at the top of that sub-tree. But this can still seem messy, especially when there's a lot of data that's needed all over your app.

The new-ish [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) feature can help with the problem of passing data through many layers of components. But it doesn't change the fact that a lot of your state and state-modifying functions are stuck in the top component.

To deal with that, you'll need to look into one of the state-management tools like [MobX](http://mobx.js.org/) or [Redux](http://redux.js.org/). Although Redux is pretty popular, I found MobX a little easier to adjust to. Basically you'll end up moving all of your application data and logic out of your React components, and into their own classes. Using [mobx-react](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react), you'll configure those classes (or some of their properties) to be "injected" directly into individual React components as properties. Then MobX will "observe" certain values in these classes, and tell the React components to re-render when they change.

It takes a little getting used to, but I've been very happy with the results. It's frustrating that most React tutorials ignore this issue, or make it sound like you only need MobX/Redux for very advanced use cases. I've found them necessary for anything beyond very simple demos.

Answer (score 0):

If a component needs to have its own state, which its parent does not care about, I don't see any reason to define it in the parent.

Defining such a state in the parent will add complexity that is not needed. It will also make maintenance difficult.

It will be much easier to understand the code and maintain it, if local state is defined where it belongs.